# Error: Multiple declaration for "pixa"

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

Пытаюсь создать указатель на массив.

```
    TRGBTriple pixa[480000];
    pixa* pix;  //Error: Multiple declaration for "pixa"
```

Хочу создать типизированный указатель pix типа pixa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pixa в первой строке - не тип, а имя массива. Если хотите сделать его типом данных, пишите так

```
typedef TRGBTriple pixa  [480000];
pixa pix; // массив переменных типа TRGBTriple размером 480000
pixa* pix; // указатель (!!!) на такой массив
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то массив и является указателем. То что тут написано пытается объявить переменную `pix` являющуюся указателем на тип `pixa`, а такого типа нет.

Если нужно создать указатель на указатель, то можно написать вот так:

`TRGBTriple** = &pixa`

Но я сомневаюсь, что это нужно, поэтому просто работайте с `pixa` как указателем на `TRGBTriple`, правда в этом случае, так как массив хранится в стеке, вы не сможете изменить его значение (значение указателя, а не того на что он укаывает). Поправьте меня, если не так.